# The magnetic field strength/intensity produced by the coil is always $\frac{NI}{l}$?

Tags: magnetic-fields

By comparison between electric field and magnetic field. The relationship between H and B is analogous to E-D relationship that

$$B=\frac{H}{\mu_0}$$

as same as

$$D=\frac{E}{\epsilon_0}$$

However there are thing I don't understand that B field is vector field however H field is not?
Base on the definition of Magnetomotive force. For a current-carrying coil having current I and N turn with length $l$:

$$F= NI = HL$$
$$\rightarrow H = \frac Fl = \frac{NI}{l}$$

All these 3 quantity (N,I,L) is scalar quantity so H is scalar quantity.
Moreover, B is a vector field that means for each point on space B is a vector with direction and value different from other point. Whereas, according to $H = \frac{NI}{l}$ then H is the same for any point in space because the length $l$ for the coil is fixed.

Comment: That H or B are constant in a coil is an approximation that holds pretty well for long coils, but it has no relevance for the actual definition of either H and B which has nothing to do with coils.

Comment: So is H a vector quantity or not. Also according to this exercise http://i.imgur.com/7UdG2g9.png. I don't understand why the length of air gap is used to calculate m.m.f while it must be the length of the coil.

Comment: H and B are vectors. You are simply mistaking a technical approximation for the field inside a coil of a particular geometry for basic physics. Truthfully, even that approximation is not good enough for most technical applications. When scientists and engineers need a really homogenous field they go with advanced versions of Helmholtz coils, instead.

Comment: $I$ is also definitely a vector, current has to flow in some direction.